# Are these two different formulas for Value-Iteration update equivalent?

Tags: formula, mdp, value-iteration

While studying MDP via different sources, I came across two different formulas for the Value update in Value-Iteration algorithm.

The first one is (the one on Wikipedia and a couple of books):

[image: First equation]
.
And the second one is (in some questions here on stack, and my course slides) : [image: Second equation]

For a specific iteration, they don't seem to give the same answer. Is one of them converging faster to the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the difference is in reward functions *R(s , s')* or R(s) in the second formula.

First equation is generalized.

In the first one, the rewards is *R<sub>a</sub>(s , s')* when transitioning from state ***`s`*** to the state ***`s'`*** due action ***`a'`***.
Reward could be different for different states and actions.

But if for every state *`s`* we have some pre-defined reward(regardless of the previous state and the action that leads to *`s`*), then we can simplify the formula to the second one.

The final values are not necessarily equal but the policies are same.